# How should I work with dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
 its(:register_token_created_at){ should eq Time.zone.now }
```

results in this failure:

```
   expected: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 13:31:53 UTC +00:00
        got: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 13:31:53 UTC +00:00

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
```

The `Diff` is even completely empty! Don't really know what I can do here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`timecop`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem.

Check out the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/276-testing-time-web-requests) about this issue.